# purrr's every doesnt work well with is.na

Tags: r, purrr

I recently used the *every* command from the purrr package and I am not sure if it works the way it was intended:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- list(1:3, "a", NA)
every(a, is.na)
[1] FALSE

b <- list(1:10)
every(b, is.na)
[1] TRUE
```

In my understanding, *every* checks if every element in a list satisfies a certain condition, in my case it checks if a component is NA.
In the first case it rightfully returns false, since only the third component is NA.
But in the second case, no element is equal to NA and it returns TRUE. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `every` expects a *predicate function* as the second argument, that is, a function that will return a single logical value given its input.

When you apply `is.na` to the first (and only) element in `b`, `1:10`, you get a result of a vector of 10 `FALSE`s, which is then tested for falseness by `rlang::is_false`. That evaluates to `FALSE` because a vector of 10 `FALSE`s is not the same as a single `FALSE`, which in turn results in `every` returning `TRUE`.

If you use a predicate function the result is as expected:

```
every(b, compose(any, is.na))
#> [1] FALSE
```

It is strange though, that when *not* using a predicate function, you don't get a warning for having a vector argument when a length 1 argument is expected. It might be worth filing an issue about this.

Comment: thank you for clarifying what exactly a predicate function is. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: One more question: how come that
every(b, is.character) returns rightfully FALSE

Comment: That's because `is.character` isn't vectorised: it's essentially the same as saying `typeof(x) == "character"`, which makes it a predicate.

Comment: I [opened an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/470) about this in the purrr GitHub repo.

Comment: `anyNA` is a (faster) builtin alternative to `compose(any, is.na)`.

Comment: @egnha Absolutely! Perhaps `compose(all, is.na)` would have been a more appropriate example to demonstrate modifying `is.na` to a predicate that **purrr** expects.